# mismatch ("text/html") of the MIME type (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, phaser-framework

I started using phaser and typescript for a school project, but when i start the local server made with node.js the browser is not able to load 3 typescript files and sends this error message:

"mismatch ("text/html") of the MIME type (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)"

for the moment i did a simple local server with node.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(8888, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:8888');
});
```

i have also an index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Game.ts"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scene/Boot.ts"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scene/GameScene.ts"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

I thought that the problem was the missing "type="text/javascript" but nothing has changed since i added it. I don't know what to do.I found many possible solutions but no one worked.

Comment: I don't think you can directly use typescript without transpiling it into Javascript. Use something like babel or better still webpack _(this has all you need webserver, transpiling, bundling ...)_

Comment: checkout this phaser starting template https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-project-template _**P.s.:** nice user name_

Comment: thank you, now i will try to understand how to use webpack. :)

Comment: If you use the official phaser template (github link I posted), you just have to follow the readyme file, to be up and running.  _(learning webpack is good a good idea, but for the start not really needed, the templates takes care of the basics)_  happy coding :)